# Markers are placed incorrectly on network profile reputation graph after zoom reset

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph

If I zoom in somewhere and then press the "reset zoom" button, it places some of the markers completely out of place:
[image: Screenshot of the bug]
What it's supposed to look like:
[image: Proper spacing.]

Browser: Safari, iOS 10.1.1

Comment: No repro on Pale Moon 26.5.0 x64 Win 10. Markers are hidden after zoom, but reappear in appropriate position on hover again.

Comment: @NathanTuggy oops, probably should have mentioned what browser I was using.

Comment: Repro on iOS Safari & Chrome, macOS Safari, Firefox & Chrome

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 62.0.3202.94 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit +SP1 and a lot of other Chrome versions on different Windows 7 computers in the past.

Comment: Repro on Chrome 65

Comment: Repro on Chrome 71

Comment: This still happens. I can reproduce it too.

Comment: This still happens for me, in chrome and edge browsers, but it happens when I toggle a site's visibility on my profile.